# Security performance Issues

Tags: 2013, document-library, security, folder

I'm kind of new in Sharepoint and I've read that you have performance issues if you set the security at the document level but this happen if you create let's say 3 folders in the library and then you have the security at the folder level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fine-grained permissions is when you break this inheritance for any securable object that is at a lower level in the hierarchy by editing the permissions (creating a unique permission assignment) on that securable object.

> We recommend that you use fine-grained permissions only when a
> business case justifies it. Fine-grained permissions can increase the
> cost to manage a deployment. Because it is inefficient to maintain
> permissions for individual users, we recommend that you use group
> permissions as much as possible. Particularly if you are using
> fine-grained permissions, you should use groups to avoid having to
> track permissions for individual user accounts. Because people can
> move in and out of teams and change responsibilities frequently, you
> might not want to track all of those changes and continually update
> the permissions for uniquely secured objects.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169567.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169566.aspx

**Security Scope – 1,000 per list (threshold)**

> The maximum number of unique security scopes set for a list should not
> exceed 1,000.
>
> A scope is the security boundary for a securable object
> and any of its children that do not have a separate security boundary
> defined.
> A scope contains an Access Control List (ACL), but unlike
> NTFS ACLs, a scope can include security principals that are specific
> to SharePoint Server. The members of an ACL for a scope can include
> Windows users, user accounts other than Windows users (such as
> forms-based accounts), Active Directory groups, or SharePoint groups.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spblog/archive/2012/03/13/security-infrastructure-related-performance-problems.aspx

Conclusion, if you adopt the path of fine grained permission then you will have to pay the price for the performance. it put more pressure on the SQL server trip.

> When a greater number of unique security scopes than the value of the
> List Query Size Threshold (default is 5,000) set to the web
> application are created for folders or documents in a list, there’s a
> significant performance degradation in SharePoint operations that
> badly affects end users operations(rendering content) as well as
> SharePoint activities like indexing SharePoint Content. After the
> number of unique security scopes exceeds the value of the List Query
> Size Threshold, SharePoint uses a code path that requires additional
> SQL round trips to analyze the scopes before rendering a view.

Answer (score 1):

Fine-grained permissions can influence security on a SharePoint farm. Potential performance issues can occur when you use fine-grained permissions.

Assign permissions at the highest possible level (Folder instead of documents). As part of this strategy, consider the following techniques:

- Put documents that require fine-grained permissions in document libraries that are defined to support each group of permissions Keep the document libraries in a separate site collection or site.
- Use different document publish levels to control access. Before a document is published, the advanced permissions and versioning settings can be set for users who can only approve items in the document library.
- For non-document libraries (lists), use the ReadSecurity and WriteSecurity permission levels. When a list is created, the owners can set the Item-level permissions to either Read access or Create and Edit access.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg128955.aspx